# How can I record that QTreeView items have been double-clicked?

Tags: python, pyqt, qtreeview, qstandarditemmodel

I have a `QTreeView` and I listen for the `doubleClicked` signal. Then if I double-click the item, I will open a text file in a `QTabwidget`. Is there any good way to record if I have already opened the text from the item?

I think maybe I should create something like a `DataFrame` to record it, but I'm not sure if this is a good solution. Any suggestions?

```
class PrjTreeModel(QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent,data):
        super(PrjTreeModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.items = datapd.DataFrame([['HHH','BBB','RRR']],columns=['UserId','ProjectId','Status']) 
        self.refreshItems()

    def refreshItems(self):
        prjId = self.items['ProjectId']
        child = ['A','B','C']
        for i,row in prjId.iteritems():
            parent = QtGui.QStandardItem(row)
            for j in child:
                parent.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem(j))
            self.appendRow(parent)

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled   
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if (role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole) and (orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal) and (self.items is not None):
            return self.items['UserId'][0]
        else:
            return QStandardItemModel.headerData(self, section, orientation, role)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    [...]
    qTreeView.setModel(PrjTreeModel())
    qTreeView.doubleClicked.connect(self.dClicked)

    self dClicked(self):
        [...]
        ## open txtfile to add in QTabWidget
        ## when doubled clicked, I don't want to open same item again
        ## how should I check the state?
```

Comment: I didn't get it do you have problem to get double click event?

Comment: sorry for my poor english :) , I mean I know how to get double clicked event,but I want to know how to record that if the item in qtreeview has been clicked.

Comment: No problem. what do you mean by record?

Comment: but you need to save this state after the program has been executed ?

Comment: yes! I want to save the state , is using DataFrame or something true/false list a good soluation ?

Comment: we need more context to help you in this case, is there a database already ? What kind of model is used with the `QTreeView`  ?

Comment: I using QTreeView with **QStandardItemModel** , then I listen QTreeView's doubledclicked event in main frame , not using database. I set the default data to the model.

Comment: the question is a bit too broad, a boolean looks good but i'm not sure if you can add it to your model easily

Comment: I add some code , maybe will let question more clearly , thanks

Comment: @RelaxZeroC. Did you see my answer? If it didn't solve your problem, can you please explain why so that I can try to improve it?

Comment: @ekhumoro sorry, I had seen your answer, but I used another way to record . I just create a dict to record if rowitem has been clicked. Anyway, thank you your suggest , I think your suggestion is better, I will try later

Comment: @RelaxZeroC. Okay. Since my answer solves your problem, would you please at least mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a flag on the double-clicked item using a custom role:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        qTreeView.setModel(PrjTreeModel())
        qTreeView.doubleClicked.connect(self.dClicked)

    def dblClicked(self, index):
        item = index.model().itemFromIndex(index)
        if not item.data(Qt.UserRole + 1):
            item.setData(True, Qt.UserRole + 1)
            print('open txt file:', item.text())
        else:
            print('already double-clicked')
```